# Spontaneous page reload

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a chat app built in node.js. On the first message between two clients, one of the clients will spontaneously reload. After the reload, I can reconnect to the server, and all is well - I can continue the chat.

I'm really not sure how to troubleshoot this, or what I should be looking for.

There's only one strange thing I've noted.

The user sockets are stored on the server by username. I've told the server to write `*username* has connected`, or `*username* has disconnected` The strange thing is that I get multiple logs of `undefined has disconnected`, and then one `*username* has disconnected`

Thanks for anything to point me in the right direction

Comment: After a page reloading, the socket id is not the same as before, so you will get a disconnection and connection in a short period of time. Are you controlling this on the server?

Comment: I'm not telling it to disconnect or reload on the server side - I'm not sure why it's reloading in the first place - that's the whole problem. And it's giving me the disconnect message more than it's giving me the connect message. I never see an `undefined  has connected' message